# How to substract two hex values

Tags: javascript

I have two variables but I don't know how to subtract `red` from `white`.

I tried `ParseInt` method to converting them to decimal and calculate and again convert to hex but it gives me a value that I can't use as color , it should give me an `aqua` color but because of invalid output I'm getting white background

```js
let white = parseInt("FFFFFF",16);
let red = parseInt("FF0000",16);
let res = (white-red).toString(16);
let box = document.getElementById("mybox");
box.style.BackgroundColor = `#${res}`;
```

Comment: `let res = (white-red).toString(16).padStart(6, '0');`

Comment: @Bravo what is `padStart`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9005917/how-to-subtract-a-color-from-another

Comment: The hex notation for colours uses two hex digits for each of the red, green and blue component of a colour. You should separate them and do calculations on each component.

Comment: [image processing - subtract one color from another in RGB color space - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20935859/subtract-one-color-from-another-in-rgb-color-space)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make the color 6 digits, by padding at the start with zeros

you can use the string method [padStart](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart) for this

```js
let white = parseInt("FFFFFF",16);
let red = parseInt("FF0000",16);
let res = (white-red).toString(16).padStart(6, '0');
console.log(`#${res}`)
```

Comment: you should run the code in the snippet before you post it.

Comment: so padstart fills it with zero?

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. yeah, a line disapeared!!!! not sure how that happened, it ended up in a comment!!!

Comment: @IhateReact in this case ... check out the documentation

Comment: Your `!` key is broken...

Comment: @Andreas - thanks - I fixed it with a hammer, but now my ONE key doesn't work